# as.matrix() behavior with lists in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, multiplication

So in R, with the data.frame being the default format, dif types are not meticulously controlled, occasionally a vector comes through to matrix multiplication as a list:

```
set.seed(123)
U = matrix(runif(20),5,4)
L = list(1,2,3,4)

L.mat = matrix(L)
L.asmat = as.matrix(L)
L.unlst = unlist(L)
L.unlst.mat = matrix(unlist(L))

print(L);                     class(L);          dim(L)
print(L.mat);             class(L.mat);      dim(L.mat)
print(L.asmat);         class(L.asmat);    dim(L.asmat)
print(L.unlst);         class(L.unlst);    dim(L.unlst)
print(L.unlst.mat); class(L.unlst.mat); dim(L.unlst.mat)

U %*% L
U %*% L.mat
U %*% L.asmat
U %*% L.unlst
U %*% L.unlst.mat


str(L)
str(L.mat)
str(L.asmat)
str(L.unlst)
str(L.unlst.mat)
```

This seems odd. based on class and dim, L.asmat, and L.unlst.mat appear to be the same, but the first is a list object with dimension attribute, adn teh second is a vector object with dimension attribute. They also appear the same in the console.

So when does this come up in practice? something like:

```
V.df = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4), b = c(2,3,4,5), c = c(3,4,5,6))
V.sel1 = c("a")
V.sel2 = c("a", "b")
V.sub1 = V.df[,V.sel1] # the dreaded drop = TRUE 
V.sub2 = V.df[,V.sel2]
V.lst1 = lapply(V.sub1, function(x) x^2)
V.lst2 = lapply(V.sub2, function(x) x^2)

U %*% V.lst1
U %*% V.lst2

U %*% as.matrix(V.lst1); as.matrix(V.lst1) # not obvious what's going on by inspection
U %*% as.matrix(V.lst2); as.matrix(V.lst2) # obviously wrong
# not obvious what's going on by inspection
class(as.matrix(V.lst1)) 
class(as.matrix(unlist(V.lst1)))
# need to check str for the true attributes
str(as.matrix(V.lst1))
str(as.matrix(V.lst2))
```

So my main point is this:

```
vec = c(1,2,3,4)
U %*% vec
U %*% as.list(vec)
U %*% as.matrix(vec)
U %*% as.matrix(as.list(vec))
U %*% as.list(as.matrix(vec))
U %*% as.list(as.matrix(as.list(vec)))
U %*% as.matrix(as.list(as.matrix(vec)))
vec.lml = as.list(as.matrix(as.list(vec))); vec.lml; str(vec.lml)
vec.mlm = as.matrix(as.list(as.matrix(vec))); vec.mlm; str(vec.mlm)
identical(vec.lml, vec.mlm)
[1] TRUE
```

I just think it's odd that the the as.list coercion dominates the as.matrix coercion. If it were up to me, I would have defined as.matrix(list) to be matrix(unlist(x)), to allow a round trip from a vector, which is the basic R data type. Or at least, when printing L.asmat in the console I would have done this:

```
     [,1]
[1,] numeric,1   
[2,] numeric,1
[3,] numeric,1 
[4,] numeric,1
```

not:

```
     [,1]
[1,] 1   
[2,] 4   
[3,] 9   
[4,] 16
```

to reveal the class of each element in the matrix.
Alternatively, maybe I'm not aware of it, but shouldn't there be a way to get the class of the object being given the dimension attribute, which makes the object a matrix? I can get "list" but only from class(c(L.asmat)).

In the end, not sure if this is a question, a rant, or a feature request, but maybe someone can explain why as.matrix(L) is defined equivalently to matrix(L) when it breaks the round trip coercion from a vector.

Comment: Yes it is the intended behavior. What do you want `U %*% as.matrix(L)` to do when `L = list(1, 2, x = list(month.abb[2:6], 1:2), y = list(1:2, letters[1:10], rnorm(4))`? It just doesn't make sense, and that is why you get an error.

Comment: I have no idea what enlightenment you expect me to find in the answers. There is certainly no call for you to insult me. If you think my question has a reasonable answer why don't you answer it?

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't it work like that? `%*%` requires matrices to operate on, or vectors that it can promote to matrices. Look at this (case 2):

```
str(matrix(list(1,2,3,4)))
List of 4
 $ : num 1
 $ : num 2
 $ : num 3
 $ : num 4
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 4 1
```

as compared to this (case 3)

```
str(unlist(list(1,2,3,4)))
 num [1:4] 1 2 3 4
```

Case 2 just produces a list, so `%*%` will throw an error. Case 3 produces a vector so the matrix multiplication works fine. For more info, I suggest looking through a guide to R's data structures. R for Data Science has [a good one](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html).

Comment: Hi, can you delete this answer so that I can delete this question? Thx